# error in setting up java on Atom

Tags: java, atom-editor

Recently I have installed Atom editor and I somehow find it pretty cool to work on.

I'm facing the following errors.

Have Installed autocomplete and runner for java but doesnt work.

Here are the Images for error and config Script.

[image: Error in running]

[image: Config Script.]

Comment: bro, your code is broken

Comment: Don't attach the images of the errors. Use images when it's an UI issue or when it might actually help people understand your question with a high level diagram or something. **Don't use images as a replacement of text**. No one is going to open that image up in a new tab and zoom in to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with the atom extensions you mentioned, but it really looks like it is working fine, since it tries to compile your code.

But that code is not a valid java program. You'll need a wrapping class and a `main`-method as a starting point for execution. The java compiler is even trying to tell you that:

```
Runner.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

This means: On the second line of Runner.java is an error. There should
be a class, an interface or an enum but there is something else.

Try to compile the hello world [hello world example of wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Examples) to get started and read that full article:

```
class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Prints the string to the console.
    }
}
```